# AnimationTimer & JavaFX: Rectangle won't move horizontally using the setTranslateX() method. How to move Rectangle?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I am trying to make a game in which I have an obstacle with the Class Rectangle, and have it slide left and right. However, although it seems like it should work, the Rectangle that I named obstacle1 does not move whatsoever.

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SemiCircleMan extends Application {


public Pane pane = new Pane();
public AnimationTimer animate;
public double obstacle1Position = 0;
public int obstacle1Direction = 1;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);

Rectangle obstacle1 = new Rectangle(100, 125, 25, 25);
    pane.getChildren().add(obstacle1);
    obstacle1Position += 3 * obstacle1Position;

animate = new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {

if (obstacle1.getX() <= 500) {
                obstacle1.setTranslateX(obstacle1Position); //attempt to only make it go right
            }

};
    animate.start();


    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}



}
```

I excluded the other code that I am sure does not affect this, as the other code only deals with moving other things. Again, with this code my obstacle1 stays still. Does anyone know how to make it slide?

Comment: Have you tried using `setX()` and `setY()`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html

Comment: I tried coping and pasting your code. It does not seem to work.

Comment: I am guessing you put very little effort into this.

Comment: Is `obstacle1.getX()` >= 500 ever?

Comment: The obstacle1's X-position starts out at 100, which is less than or equal to 500. It is my fault for copying the code wrong onto here, but it doesn't move if I use "<=" or ">=". I can post the entire game code if you'd like.

Comment: I also programmed it so that it continuously changes its X-coordinate by 3 every time, so for how I set it up setX() wouldn't work since it will just put the Rectangle with that X-coordinate and that is it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has (at least) two problems.

1. `obstacle1Position` is always zero.
2. You assume that the x-value will change if you set translateX. This is not true. The x-value belongs to the geometry and translateX modifies only its transform.

Answer (score 0):

A sample app that shows how to move a `Rectangle` using `AnimationTimer`. One of the things you did not do in your code is get the `Rectangle's` current location and move from there.

**In your case**

```
rectangle.setTranslateX(rectangle.getTranslateX() + direction * speed);
```

**Equivalent code in the sample app**

```
rectangle.setX(rectangle.getX() + direction * speed);
```

> Full Code:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication235 extends Application
{

    double speed = 3;
    double direction = 1;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(100, 125, 25, 25);

        AnimationTimer animationTimer = new AnimationTimer()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now)
            {
                rectangle.setX(rectangle.getX() + direction * speed);
            }
        };
        animationTimer.start();

        Pane root = new Pane(rectangle);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```