# JavaFX: moving Rectangle with AnimationTimer

Tags: java

I am trying to code a very simple Pong-game, I think that is the name of this old game where a ball bounces between the player and a bunch of bricks with the ball going up and down. The player can move horizontally at the bottom.

So basically just some moving rectangles, eventually they are supposed to collide and so on.

However, I can allow the player to move the Rectangle with the buttons, but I can't manage to make objects move with the help of the AnimationTimer. (javafx.animation.AnimationTimer)

I already searched a lot but only found examples with mistakes that I managed to avoid.
(eg. like this [AnimationTimer & JavaFX: Rectangle won't move horizontally using the setTranslateX() method. How to move Rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51699560/animationtimer-javafx-rectangle-wont-move-horizontally-using-the-settranslat)).
I tried debugging it to see where the unexpected happens, but I couldn't find it. here is my code:

```
package bounceBall;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BounceBallApp  extends Application {

    private Pane root = new Pane();
    private Sprite player =  new Sprite(400, 500, 40, 4, "player", Color.BLUE);
    private boolean play;

    private Parent createContent() {
        this.play = false;
        root.setPrefSize(800, 600);

    root.getChildren().add(player);

    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            update();
        }

    };

    timer.start();

    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
            Sprite s = new Sprite(20*x, y*8, 18, 5, "brick", Color.AQUA);
            root.getChildren().add(s);
        }
    }

    return root;
}


private List<Sprite> getSprites(){
    List<Sprite> list = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
    for (Node n : root.getChildren()) {
        if (n instanceof Sprite) {
            Sprite s = (Sprite)n;
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
    return list;
}



private void update() {

    getSprites().forEach(b -> {
        if (b.type.equals("bullet")) {
            b.moveRight(b.getXspeed());
            b.moveDown(b.getYspeed());
        }
    });
}



@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());

    scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        //as soon as any key gets hit the game starts with the shoot method
        if (play == false) {
            shoot(player);
            play = true;
        }

        switch (e.getCode()) {
            case A:{
                player.moveLeft(10);
                break;
            }
            case D:{
                player.moveRight(10);
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Bounce Ball");
    primaryStage.show();

}



/*this method should be called once at the beginning to initiate the ball
the ball appears but it doesn't move, instead remains still
if I try to make the player move with AnimationTimer it doesn't work either, it works just by pressing keys*/

private void shoot(Sprite who) {
    Sprite s = new Sprite((int)who.getTranslateX(), (int)who.getTranslateY()-2, 4, 4, "bullet", Color.BLACK);
    s.setYspeed(-10);
    root.getChildren().add(s);
    System.out.println(root.getChildren().size());
}


private static class Sprite extends Rectangle {

    final String type;
    private int Xspeed, Yspeed;

    public Sprite(int x, int y, int w, int h, String type, Color color) {
        super(w, h, color);
        this.type = type;
        setTranslateX(x);
        setTranslateY(y);
        Xspeed = 0;
        Yspeed = 0;
    }

    public void moveLeft(int d) {
        setTranslateX(getTranslateX() - d);
    }

    public void moveRight(int d) {
        setTranslateX(getTranslateX() + d);
    }

    public void moveUp(int d) {
        setTranslateX(getTranslateY() - d);
    }

    public void moveDown(int d) {
        setTranslateX(getTranslateY() + d);
    }

    public int getXspeed() {
        return Xspeed;
    }

    public int getYspeed() {
        return Yspeed;
    }

    public void setXspeed(int xspeed) {
        Xspeed = xspeed;
    }

    public void setYspeed(int yspeed) {
        Yspeed = yspeed;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

I expect the ball to go straight up at the beginning but it appears at the wrong position (ca. 50px right from where I expect).
Most importantly it doesn't move.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try it with `setTranslateY` instead of `setTranslateX` in the methods `moveUp` and `moveDown`.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you so much! how could I not see this. It works now, thanks!